# Selenium WebDriver Internet Explorer IEDriverServer Blocks Modal Dialog

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I'm testing an application that opens a lot of modal dialogs using Javascript `window.showModalDialog` method. My Selenium Webdriver code works fairly well with `Firefox`. However, it encounters various problems with Internet Explorer 11 using `IEDriverServer`.

On one page, when a link is clicked manually (by just launching IE) or by Selenium on FF, a new modal dialog is opened.

[image]

However, on a browser opened by IEDriverServer, nothing happens. I can't even click on it manually either. It's as if there's an invisible layer of something that's blocking this instance of the browser altogether.

[image]

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: #JimEvans - Can you please shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems.IeDriver is not responsible for this.I suggest you run vs with administrator privileges, or you run compiled programs with administrator privileges.Finding this method is not easy, after all, it's not a code problem.